# phpmyadmin move to another server?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Ok so I've got phpmyadmin running on my local server for web development, however, my server has crashed, but I have a backup of all the files (not a database backup) on my server from last night, if I copy across the phpmyadmin folder, and put it on another machine, will all my databases still be in tact?

Comment: No, phpmyadmin is only interface to databases, except if you copy phisical database files and can run them on new instance of sql

Comment: PHPMyAdmin is only a database administration tool. You'll need to access your database directory to retreive your database.

Comment: Sorry to sound stupid, but where's the database directory found in phpmyadmin folders? If it is found in there, that is :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your database files are probably in /var/lib/mysql.  If you have THOSE files backed up, with EXACTLY the same version of mysql, same libraries, etc., then you could just restore them to another machine, and check the configuration for hostnames (MySQL only uses these IN the database though, for login security, iirc, so it won't apply until you're up and running again).  Then, just boot it up.  Do keep a copy of the backed up /var/lib/mysql though, in case it fails to come up correctly.  MySQL will probably repair some files on startup, which may not work properly.

Once you can do pgrep -l mysql (as root), and you see mysql running, then you can worry about installing a webserver, php, phpmyadmin, etc.

Next time, have proper, regular backups (mysqldump plus a filesystem backup using something like rdiff-backup, dirvish, or faubackup), use a redundant RAID filesystem, and maybe a data-checksummed filesystem on top, like ZFS.

Answer (score 1):

Phpmyadmin is only interface to database engine. You can dump databases trough it, but it is not the database engine. If your server is still alive (ssh or command prompt), and you have live mysql instance you can dump your databases to sql file, using the command **[mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)**, and restore them on the new server with phpmyadmin or just using mysql -u user -p | cat sqlfile.sql